# Where do I locate theme image files

Tags: images

I have a webpage built by another company years ago. The header has a long image above it. I need to edit the image and replace it. I have been searching for 2 days, I cannot find where that image is stored on my wordpress dashboard. It is not in my Media>Library. I do not see where it could be Themes>Editor. Any tips please?

I have located the image address using Dev Tool, but I cant figure out how to access it. http://www.topnotchgaragedoor.com/wp-content/themes/topnotch/images/header.jpg

Comment: Check the theme's header.php file, it could be hardcoded

Comment: I have located the image address using Dev Tool, but I cant figure out how to access it. http://www.topnotchgaragedoor.com/wp-content/themes/topnotch/images/header.jpg

Comment: This is something that could be access with an FTP client, like Filezilla. Judging by the URL for the image, it looks like it was hard-coded into the theme, as it is being stored in the theme's directory, instead of being stored in WordPress's media directory. So you'll have to access this via FTP, not via the WordPress admin.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use the developer tools in your browser; see [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to look at the rendered browser source to locate the URL for the image. The image could be loading from a third party, the theme folder, etc.

Using dev tools is more reliable than simply viewing browser source, as the image could be loading via ajax from the theme folder or a third party and that won't show up in static page source.

Another way to find code and links in site is to use a text editor that can search all the contents of a folder of files; that way, you can search the entire theme folder for links and code, unlike the theme editor in the Wordpress back end, which only allows you to look at files one at a time.

Comment: I have located the image address using Dev Tool, but I cant figure out how to access it. http://www.topnotchgaragedoor.com/wp-content/themes/topnotch/images/header.jpg

Comment: Why can't you use FTP?

Comment: I'll need to learn how.

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients